# apache2 fails to load because the process exited with error code

Tags: networking, server, apache2, network-manager, openvpn

As stated in the question, i installed apache2 in my ubuntu but the https server failed to load . I tried to investigate and journalctl gives the following output:

```
$ journalctl _PID=9176
-- Logs begin at Fri 2020-02-21 23:19:35 IST, end at Tue 2020-03-03 19:09:21 IST. --
Mar 03 19:09:21 node1 apachectl[9176]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 2401:4900:30b1:ccc8:184b:e745:5b8b:c562. Set the 'ServerName' directive globa
Mar 03 19:09:21 node1 apachectl[9176]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Mar 03 19:09:21 node1 apachectl[9176]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Mar 03 19:09:21 node1 apachectl[9176]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Mar 03 19:09:21 node1 apachectl[9176]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Mar 03 19:09:21 node1 apachectl[9176]: Action 'start' failed.
Mar 03 19:09:21 node1 apachectl[9176]: The Apache error log may have more information.
```

I am unable to understand the real problem and how to solve it. Some help?

Comment: Network port 80 is already in use .. either apache is already running, or some other process is listening on the port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some soft already use port 80 and apache2 could not start.
I think you must stop another web server (for example nginx)
run `netstat -lnp` and search what program use port tcp 80

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1223/nginx: master      
tcp6      0      0 :::80                        :::*                        LISTEN      1223/nginx: master               above is the output of the command as u said it is being used by nginx.....how do i stop that??

Comment: Run `sudo service nginx stop`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214543/apache2-fails-to-load-because-the-process-exited-with-error-code#comment2040931_1214545), the service `nginx` is running, using the `:80` port:

To stop the service:

```
sudo systemctl stop nginx
```

To disable the service:

```
sudo systemctl disable nginx
```

Comment: nginx has been stopped but apache still gives the same error and the :80 port is not in use. Need to fix that